# Problems submitting multiple forms with ajaxSubmit / jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some code as such to submit multiple forms on my page at once:

```
$('.photo-edit-form form').ajaxSubmit({
     success: function() { console.log('success'); },
     error: function() { console.log('error'); }
});
```

However, no matter how many forms I have, I only ever get one success print out. I've found that I can fix it by using .each on the selected forms like so:

```
$('.photo-edit-form form').each(function() {
     $(this).ajaxSubmit({
          success: function() { console.log('success'); },
          error: function() { console.log('error'); }
     });
});
```

Is this a problem with the ajaxForm plugin or is this a misunderstanding on my part about how jQuery works? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the plugin *acts* like it handles any number at once, but [it basically comes down to this](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L170):

```
$.ajax(options);
```

And the [`data` in that option set](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L122) [comes from](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L85) `.formToArray()` [which only deals with the first element in the set](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L518):

```
var form = this[0];
```

So for your question, **yes, this is a problem with the plugin**, `.ajaxSubmit()` only works on a single `<form>` at a time, it doesn't have a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) internally like most plugins would.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I see it ajaxSubmit does not handle each result from the selector.